# NSIS - Variable is not resolving properly

Tags: variables, nsis

I'm trying to check the version of folder with !define variable from compiler.nsh. On mismatch of version, I'm trying to update compiler.nsh with ReplaceInFile macro. But the Filepath I have provided on the ReplaceInFile macro is not resolving variable ${CURRENT_KIT}. Am I missing something? Please help

```
;***************************************************************************************
; Version Check 
;***************************************************************************************
Var /GLOBAL CURRENT_KIT
Var /GLOBAL CURRENT_VER


;Function CompilerFile
Section 
    System::Call "kernel32::GetCurrentDirectory(i ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}, t .r0)"

    ${WordFind} "$0" "\" "-1" "$CURRENT_KIT"
    ${CharStrip} "${APP_CLASSKIT}"  "$CURRENT_KIT" "$CURRENT_VER"
    
    Push "$CURRENT_VER"
    Push "${CHK_VERSION}"
    Call VersionCheck
    Pop $0
    
    ${If} $0 == 0
    MessageBox MB_OK "Kit Version matches compiler.nsh"
    !define APP_VERSION "${CHK_VERSION}"
    ${ElseIf} $0 == 1
        !insertmacro _ReplaceInFile **"${NETWORK_PATH}\${CURRENT_KIT}\compiler.nsh"** '!define CHK_VERSION "${CHK_VERSION}"' '!define APP_VERSION "$CURRENT_VER"'

    ${EndIf}
```

Comment: It seems to me like this is related to your previous question which is still unresolved?

Comment: Actually, I skipped to create a batch file. Instead, I use Version check function to compare version and using ReplaceInFile macro, I call the path of compiler and update the file directly by searching string. So, I'm sort of on same error when trying different approach.

Comment: You are still mixing up defines and variables it seems to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you are trying to do but if I am guessing the variable can not be resolved this way.

Rather try this syntax for resolving the variables in a string:

```
!insertmacro _ReplaceInFile **"${NETWORK_PATH}\$CURRENT_KIT\compiler.nsh"** '!define CHK_VERSION "${CHK_VERSION}"' '!define APP_VERSION "$CURRENT_VER"'
```

You don't need the extra curly brackets for these kind of variables.

Let me know if I helped you with your issue.